Bounds on shifted matrix exponential
Let $A,B$ be real square matrices. If I know that
$ \| e^{i \omega A} \|$ is bounded over $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$, then how do I prove that $ \| e^{i \omega A + B} \|$ is too?
Context:
The transfer function between boundary conditions for a particular type of 1D linear hyperbolic PDE is of the form $e^{As + B}$, where $s \in \mathbb{C}$. If it is bounded over the closed right half-plane, this proves stability. Now $B$ is a damping term, so if the transfer function is stable for $B=0$, then it ought to be so for the right type of $B$. In my application $B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & X \\ Y & 0 \end{bmatrix} $, where $X,Y$ are real symmetric positive-definite.

why do you think the result is true? can you give us context, tries etc - the question would be closed otherwise and it's actually quite interesting

I really do not understand the rush to close.

I don't understand how this works either. I just added some context, hopefully they will reopen.

It is bounded. The result can be found in [1, Proposition 4.2.18].
[1] D. Hinrichsen and A. J. Pritchard, Mathematical Systems Theory I, vol. 48. in Texts in Applied Mathematics, vol. 48. Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer, 2005. doi: 10.1007/b137541.
